# Dynamically returning property values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class like:

```
Class A
{
        public double? LondonTime { get; set; }
        public double? DelhiTime { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in my another class, I want to make these properties dynamic.
`Class B` has a function `foo(ClassA)`:

```
Class B

private void foo(Class A)
double d;
{
 If(some condition for London Time)
  {
    //How to pass LondonTime Property
    d = returnTime(); 
   }
 else if(some condition for Delhi Time)
 {
   //How to pass DelhiTimeProperty
    d = returnTime();
 }
}

private double returnTime(????) //What should I Pass here as an argument
{
  if(LondonTimeProperty Passed)
  {
    Some logic
  }
  if(DelhiTimeProperty Passed)
  {
    Some logic
  }  
  return 0;
}
```

Here, this is just an example, if it was just giving me 1 dynamic value, I can adjust it.

So, is there a way that I pass an argument in `returnTime` based on some condition and know what to return ?

Answer (score 2):

Some general questions and comments:

Why are you using a `double` instead of a `DateTime`?

What do you mean by dynamic?

It seems like all you need is this:

```
double? GetLondonTime(A a)
{
    //Some logic
}

double? GetDelhiTime(A a)
{
    //Some logic
}

void foo(A a)
{
    If(some condition for Delhi)
        return GetDelhiTime(a);
    If(some condition for London)
        return GetLondonTime(a);
    return 0;
}
```

If you were using a `DateTime`, you could probably determine if it was Delhi or London time based on the `TimeZone`.

Comment: I like your comment at the end about the timezone, something like this might work too: `var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;`
+1

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
 public static dynamic GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propName)
        {
            return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(obj, null);
        }
```

and then you can use:

```
GetPropertyValue(new ClassA(),"LondonTime");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I don't really see a reason to complicate it by doing reflection or dynamic objects, unless there is a lot more going on:

```
    public class Times {
    public enum : int City {
        LONDON,
        NEW_DEHLI,
        OTHER_PLACE
    };
    public /*DateTime*/double GetTime(City) {
        switch(City) {
            case City.NEW_DEHLI:
            return getDehliTime();
        case City.London:
            return getLondonTime();
        default:
            return DateTime.Now;
        }
    } 
}
```